# drop function source code in R

Tags: r

I am trying to find source code of `drop` function but all I am getting is `.Rd` file or references where it is used.

I searched it in following URLS:

https://github.com/wch/r-source/search?p=2&q=drop&utf8=%E2%9C%93

https://github.com/wch/r-source/search?p=3&q=drop&utf8=%E2%9C%93

```
edit(drop)
```

fetched me this:

```
function (x) 
.Internal(drop(x))
```

Can anyone help me out here?

Comment: @Pascal, are drop and droplevels same?

Comment: @Pascal, I need drop for dropping array dimensions, that is "drop'. 'droplevels' are used for factors.

Comment: The `drop` function calls [this](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/trunk/src/main/array.c#L390-L408). Which in turn uses [this](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/trunk/src/main/array.c#L282-L388). A good place for looking for C functions in R is [here](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/trunk/src/main/names.c)